# Контроль суммы, от 1000 до 1999 и от 2000 и более

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста, на странице есть вот такой сегмент кода:

```html
<div class="front_buttons">
  <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="billButtons" style="display: table;">
    <tbody>
      <tr valign="middle">
        <td style="padding-left:13px;">
          <div id="bill_sale_block"></div>
        </td>
        <td width="200" align="center">
          <div style="font-size:16px;">К оплате <b id="bill_total">890</b> руб.</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr height="50">
        <td>
          <div onclick="tooltip('bill_sale_tooltip',this);" class="btn bill grey persent"><span></span></div>
          <div id="bill_client_score" class="btn bill grey more" style="display:none;" onclick="">Счет
            <div class="mb"></div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
          <div onclick="orderSave();" class="btn bill save save" style="margin-right:10px; float:right;">Сохранить</div>
          <div onclick="billBasketClear();" class="btn bill grey trash" style="float:right;"><span></span></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Необходимо контролировать сумму в:

```html
<div style="font-size:16px;">К оплате <b id="bill_total">890</b> руб.</div>
```

Если она равна или превышает 1000 (до 1999), то выполнять:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('item')[1].click();
```

если 2000 и более (до 10000) то выполнять:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('item')[2].click();
```

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Два вопроса: что делается по клику на item[1-2]? И в какой момент надо кликать? Как страница загрузилась? Ну и... где в разметке class=item?

Comment: По клику активируются две скидки, они уже есть в коде, их просто нужно активировать, при условии изменения общей суммы заказа, код большой весь сбрасывать не стал, то что сбросил недостаточно?